# Why do I need to specify ElementName and DataContext in a binding?

Tags: wpf

To familiarize myself with WPF and MVVM concepts I built a visual representation of a Sudoku board.

My (simplified) setup looks like this (no custom code-behind in views anywhere):

I have a MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Sudoku.WPF.MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <models:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ctrl:SudokuBoard DataContext="{Binding Path=GameViewModel}"/>
</Window>
```

My MainWindowViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        IGame g = new Game(4);
        this.GameViewModel = new GameViewModel(g);
    }

    public IGameViewModel GameViewModel { get; private set; }
}
```

SudokuBoard is a `UserControl`. Its `DataContext` is set to `GameViewModel` as per above.
Relevant parts of `GameViewModel`, `Elements` is populated in the ctor, `Possibilities` is set via a command:

```
public IList<CellViewModel> Elements { get; private set; }
private bool _showPossibilities;
public bool ShowPossibilities
{
    get { return _showPossibilities; }
    set
    {
        _showPossibilities = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In `SudokuBoard.xaml` I have:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="SudokuGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ToggleContentStyle}"
                            Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`Elements` is a collection of `CellViewModel`s generated in the constructor of `GameViewModel`.

Now to the question: my `ToggleContentStyle` as defined in `<UserControl.Resources>`:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleContentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowPossibilities, ElementName=SudokuGrid}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource valueTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowPossibilities, ElementName=SudokuGrid}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource possibilityTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(both `ContentTemplate`s just show other properties of a single `CellViewModel`  in different representations)

Question 1: I have to explicitly reference `DataContext` in order to get to the `ShowPossibilities` property. If I leave it out, so that `Path=ShowPossibilities`, I get a `UniformGrid` with the `ToString()` representation of `CellViewModel`. My assumption is that that is because the style is referenced from the `ItemTemplate`, with it's binding set to a single `CellViewModel`. Is that assumption valid?

Question 2: When I omit the `ElementName` part, I also get the `ToString()` representation of `CellViewModel`. Now I'm really confused. Why is it needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datacontext is a dependency property which is marked as inherits.  That means its inherited down the visual tree.

When you bind the default place it's going to look for a source is in the datacontext.

This is the simple situation.

Say you have a window and that has datacontext set to WindowViewmodel and stick a textbox in that Window. You bind it's Text to FooText. This means the textbox goes and looks for a FooText property in that instance of WindowViewmodel.

All pretty simple so far.

Next...

You use elementname.

What that does is says go and take a look at this element. Look for a property on that. If you did that with our textbox above then it would expect a dependency property FooText on whatever you point it to.

Datacontext is a dependency property.

And when you do:

```
   "{Binding FooProperty
```

This is shorthand for:

```
   "{Binding Path=FooProperty
```

Where FooProperty is a property path, not =just the name of a property.

Which is maybe worth googling but means you can use "dot notation" to walk down the object graph and grab a property on an object ( on an object.... ).

Hence DataContext.Foo or Tag.Whatever ( since tag is another dependency property a control will have ).

Let's move on to some other complications.

The datcontext is inherited down the visual tree but there's a few of gotchas here. Since 
some things look like they're controls but are not ( like datagridtextcolumn ). Templated things can be tricky. Itemscontrols are a kind of obvious and relevent special case.

For an itemscontrol, the datacontext of anything in each row is whichever item it's presented to from the itemssource. Usually you're binding an observablecollection of rowviewmodel to that itemssource. Hence ( kind of obviously ) a listbox or datagrid shows you the data from each rowviewmodel you gave it in each row.

If you then want to go get a property is not in that rowviewmodel you need to tell it to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you specify an element in Binding (eg ElementName=SudokuGrid), the Path has to refer to any property of that element. Because this element is a wpf control, DataContext is one of it's properties but ShowPossibilities isn't. So if you do just Path=ShowPossibilities it will not be able to find that path at all.
2. If you don't specify element in Binding at all then it defaults to the DataContext associated with the control. If the associated DataContext doesn't have the property ShowPossibilities it will not be able to find it.

PS: If you want to debug wpf UI to see what the DataContext is at run-time you could use utility like Snoop.

Comment: Thanks for the Snoop tip!